# Link_to and Ajax request Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, instance-variables

Hopefully I can explain this so people can understand what i am trying to achieve. Currently I have multiple posts being created and they are shown at this url for public view

```
/tynewyddnews
```

as opposed to the standard

```
/posts/:id
```

which is only available to the admin user

The page is split into 2, the latest post on taking up most of the page and historical posts listed down the left hand side of the page, each rendered slightly different through a scope

Scope

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, :order => "posts.published_on DESC"
```

Latest Post

```
@tynewyddpostlatest = Post.tynewydd_posts.first
```

Historical Posts

```
tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts.reverse
tynewyddpost.pop
@tynewyddpost = tynewyddpost
```

In my view i render each like so

Left hand side

```
<% @tynewyddpost.reverse.each do |t| %>
<%= link_to t.title, t %>
```

Main

```
<%= @tynewyddpostlatest.title %>
```

What i would like to achieve is that when clicking the link for a post on the left hand side it will render in place of the main post in the center via ajax. What i have come up with so far works to a point, the title and comments render via the ajax call but the photos for the post i have clicked haven't rendered in the view, even though when in firebug they are showing as being rendered.(though they have a size of 0x0 px)

left hand side posts

```
<% @tynewyddpost.reverse.each do |t| %>
<%= link_to t.title, tynewyddnews_path(:type => 'tynewyddnews'), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

tynewyddnews.js.erb

```
<% if params[:type] == 'tynewyddnews' %>
 $('.post-item').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tynewyddnewspost') %>');
<% end %>
```

partial

```
<div class="post-item">
  <% @tynewyddpost.each do |t| %>
   <h2><%= t.title %></h2>
    <div id="work-samples"> 
     <% for photo in t.photos %>
      <%= image_tag(photo.avatar.url(:news_images), :class => 'work-sample') %>
     <% end %>
   </div>  
  <p class="post-description"><%= t.comments.html_safe %></p><a class="post-more" href="#">Continue Reading&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
   <div class="post-item-panel">
      <ul>
       <li class="date">
        <p><%= date_output(t.published_on) %></p>
       </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

many thanks

Comment: How do you get `@tynewyddpost`? It is nil and that's why it's throwing the exception

Comment: hello, if you look at my historical posts in the question, thats how i get @tynewyddpost

Comment: oh, sorry. Anyways it looks like your variable is nil

Comment: im a litte lost, so what should i use as my variable in the partial? ive tried @tynewyddpost.title for example and it still says nill for Array

Comment: so do i need to setup a block to loop through as its an array being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove this line firstly:

```
<%= @tynewyddpostlatest.title %>
```

And try if the error keeps showing. If it does, can you remove:

```
<% @tynewyddpost.reverse.each do |t| %>
<%= link_to t.title, t %>
```

Does the error still show?

Comment: think i got it, I had to setup a loop and now just noticed your answer.though  photos not showing, ive used @tynewyddpost.each do |t|

Comment: weird thing with the images is that if i inspect element over the div containing the photos they are being rendered and i can hover over the link to see them, but just not showing in the view

Comment: i am currently completely lost, sorry. Can you shorten the question somehow or update it or move it to another one? dough, i don't really know what the problem may be, but the question you gave is big and confusing

Comment: or close this one and open a new one so you won't have to erase all the comments..and so that other people can see it as the newest one :)

Comment: ah i have edited now, though still quite long :( maybe just update your answer if you can?

Comment: what is? `:news_images`? Are you using Paperclip? Is that a `style`?

Comment: yes using paperclip, :news_images is supposed to be 250px x 180px

Comment: Do you know how to show images usually or is this your first time you are trying to show a image?

Comment: Are you storing them on your local computer?

Comment: Yes I am storing them on local machine

Comment: Yes it's strange, everywhere else on the site I use it they render fine, just in this Ajax call they are not

Comment: I really don't know, sorry

Comment: That's ok, thanks for your help though, seems you are helping me with a lot :)

Comment: Haha, no problem, glad I can :)